# How to get waved vertical borders with box shadow

Tags: css

I am trying to get a waved vertical borders with a box-shadow like this.
[image]

I am able to get the waved vertical borders but when adding box-shadow, it overlaps the waves as the waves are not statically positioned and don't directly belong to the container's vertical borders.

Comment: Please add your code and what you have tried!

Comment: use filter: drop-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Use a different div for shadow with exact or slightly fewer dimensions than that of the wavy-border div. Use `position: absolute;` on both divs and give the wavy-border div a higher `z-index` to make it appear on the top of the shadow div. Set the yellow shadow but on the shadow div as you want. This way the shadow won't interfere with the wavy border.

You may want to put both divs in the same parent div and set the parent's display to relative. If you don't the absolute nature of wavy-border and shadow divs will be based on body and not the proper position in your HTML.

You can also use `filter: drop-shadow(...);` as Temani Afif mentioned in the comment. When doing this, you won't need to use two different divs. You just set the drop-shadow directly on the wavy-border div. drop-shadow makes it possible to shadow exactly based on the content, instead of based on a box.